# MySql join tables with filter at one of table

Tags: mysql

noobs here.

i have 2 master tables its **employees** and **trainings** each of that table has primary key
and 1 table **training_histories** to mapping employee to training that have been taken. so my scheema looks like this.

```
table employees : id, employee_name, etc.

table trainings : id, training_name, etc.

table training_histories : id, employee_id, training_id
```

I want to do a query to find out which employees have been included in a particular training with the training_id parameter.

i try this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees AS emp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_training_histories AS th ON emp.emp_id = th.emp_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN trainings AS trn ON th.training_id = trn.training_id 
WHERE th.training_id = 1
```

but its not works like my expectations

i expect when training_id = 1 its showing like this

| employee | training |
| --- | --- |
| a | javascript |
| b | javascript |
| c | null |
| d | null |

when training_id = 2 its showing like this

| employee | training |
| --- | --- |
| a | null |
| b | C++ |
| c | C++ |
| d | null |

still showing all employee but training is depending on training_id

thanks for attention forgive me for my bad engglish..

Comment: The condition by right table must be placed into ON, not into WHERE.

Comment: You provide desired output without source data. Add source data which results in this outputs - as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: You should read [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join), and, after reading, re-write your query.

Comment: thanks for your comment @Akina , i use ON clause for optimal results. and i need to learn again about join consep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch from `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.You can see the difference between the various joins [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join).

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM employees AS emp 
INNER JOIN employee_training_histories AS th ON emp.emp_id = th.emp_id 
INNER JOIN trainings AS trn ON (th.training_id = trn.training_id AND th.training_id = 1)
```

###### P.S: You can directly place your filter in the `ON` clause for optimal results.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i need to read more about join consept..

i use your PS about ON clouse and its works for my case, thankyou so much